# MySQL INSERT only if two fields don't match

Tags: mysql, insert, match

I have 6 fields with the primary as ID and is set to auto_increment.  I want to INSERT a new row if DATE and FROM **do not** match.  I was thinking of `REPLACE INTO` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but from what I know I have to have one of them as my Primary? I don't care how its done I just need some help with a query that would work.

```
ID

DATE        

STORE               

TOTAL           

NPS     

FROM
```

Comment: Sounds like DATE and FROM are a secondary key.  In which case you can handle this using your server side code.  The secondary key will ensure that all FROM and DATE combinations are unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is a unique index composed of both the DATE and FROM fields.

`ALTER TABLE table ADD UNIQUE INDEX(DATE, FROM);`

Then you can use this type of query:

`INSERT IGNORE INTO table (columns) VALUES (...)`

The IGNORE statement will skip any INSERT that would otherwise cause a duplicate key error.