# MySQL: Insert only if

Tags: mysql

I would like to insert a row only if two values(or more) of the query is different:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, title, description) 
VALUES(1, 'hello', 'world') 
ONLY IF title AND description DOESN't ALREADY EXISTS
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL INSERT only if two fields don't match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475670/mysql-insert-only-if-two-fields-dont-match)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `replace into` if you add a unique key on the two columns

```
REPLACE INTO table (id, title, description) 
VALUES(1, 'hello', 'world')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, TITLE, DESCRIPTION) VALUES (1, 'hello', 'world')
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TABLE WHERE TITLE='hello' AND DESCRIPTION='world') = 0
```

Comment: As I know it's not possible to use `WHERE` with `INSERT`, but I have tried your solution and it's not working, what I'm doing wrong? :\